# Anaconda3 2.4 with python 3.5 installation error (procedure entry not found; Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, failed-installation

I have just made up my mind to change from python 2.7 to python 3.5 and therefore tried to reinstall Anaconda (64 bit) with the 3.5 environment. When I try to install the package I get several errors in the form of (translation from German, so maybe not exact):

> The procedure entry "__telemetry_main_return_trigger" could not be found in the DLL "C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe".

and

> The procedure entry "__telemetry_main_invoke_trigger" could not be found in the DLL "C:\Anaconda3\python35.dll".

The title of the second error message box still points to pythonw.exe. Both errors appear several times - every time an extraction was completed. The installation progress box reads

> [...]
>
> extraction complete.
>
> Execute: "C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" "C:\Anaconda3\Lib_nsis.py" postpkg

After torturing myself through the installation I get the warning

> Failed to create Anaconda menus

If I ignore it once gives me my lovely error messages and tells me that

> Failed to initialize Anaconda directories

then

> Failed to add Anaconda to the system PATH

Of course nothing works, if I dare to use this mess it installs. What might go wrong? On other computers with Windows 10 it works well.

P.S.: An installation of Anaconda2 2.4 with python 2.7 works without any error message, but still is not able to be used (other errors).

Comment: The Python 3.5 version of anaconda is quite new. You're more likely to get a bug free experience if you stick to the Python 3.4 version for just now, if that's acceptable. You can always upgrade anaconda or individual packages later if needed.

Comment: Thank you. I will try an older version, although the new package works on my machine at home. Very strange, because also the new Anaconda2 package has issues.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I have found the reason. So, if anybody else has this problem:

[Here](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/YI-obkGV4oU) the entry points are an issue as well and Michael Sarahan gives the solution. Install the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145), which is used by the new version of python, first. After that install the Anaconda-package and it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use your standard Anaconda installation and just create an environment based on 2.7 / 3.4 etc... Anaconda will download and install all compatible packages from the repository so you have a complete installation.

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda

conda create -n py34 python=3.4 anaconda
```

To use the new environment (in Windows), you can point your IDE to the required environment folder:

```
C:\Anaconda3\envs\py34\python.exe
```

On the Windows command line, you just need to type:

```
activate py34
```

Documentation:
http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html

My recommendation would be to reinstall your Anaconda version with Python 2.7 that you previously had working, then just add a new environment for Python 3.x and use that as you need.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, then I Installed "for all users": solved.
Much easier than the links provided for a beginner as I am.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem "Failed to create Anaconda menus", it may because:
This might happen if PATH is too long already. How long is your PATH environment variable?  Windows limits this to 1024 characters.  There are some workarounds go shorten it here: [How do you avoid over-populating the PATH Environment Variable in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405091/how-do-you-avoid-over-populating-the-path-environment-variable-in-windows)

This is other people's question and solution
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/mjrbE6rKyi8

When I shorted the environment path, it works!

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting errors like: 
    Failed to create Anaconda menus
    Failed to initialize Anaconda directories
    Failed to add Anaconda to the system PATH
just ignore them while installation and when installation is done look for the directory "anaconda3" is installed and correct the path accordingly in environment variables path.
In my system, path was set "C:\Anaconda3" but actually it was installed at "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3". You have to change all 3 path entries for anaconda3 and then try to run "jupyter notebook" in CMD.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, launch the command prompt as administrator and execute the following commands

1. "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib_nsis.py" addpath
2. "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib_nsis.py" mkdirs
3. "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe" -E -s "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib_nsis.py" mkmenus

Don't forget to change the path to the path in your system. Before running this commands there will not be any Anaconda Navigator app in your start menu. After executing this commands make sure Anaconda Navigator app is available in the start menu.

Answer (score 0):

Change the directory. It works
C:\miniconda3

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).