# Visual Studio 2015 & Cordova 5.4.1: could not debug Android app

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

After recent update of Cordova CLI from 4.3.0 to 5.4.1 I faced the following issue: when trying to debug my app on Android device the VS simply couldn't start debugging session.

I tried to incease verbosity level in the MSBuild output, but there are still no evident errors, nothing.

Here is my output window:

```
Installing app on device...
Launching application...
LAUNCH SUCCESS
Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c "app_dir\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat --debug --nobuild --buildConfig="app_dir\app_name\build.json --target=android_device_id"
Executing "after_run"  hook for all plugins.
2>  
The format of cordova.raw.* methods "options" argument was changed in 5.4.0. "options.options" property now should be an object instead of an array of plain strings. Though the old format is still supported, consider updating your cordova.raw.* method calls to use new argument format.
========== Build: success: 1, errors: 0, unchanged: 0, skipped: 0 ==========
========== Deployment: success: 0, errors: 1, skipped: 0 ==========
```

So, the app is deployed, started on device and then VS simply can't start debugger.

Does anyone experience the similar issue?  I'm sure that it's related to the latest Cordova CLI but don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Can you try cli 5.3.3 instead and let me know if that works? There are several issues with 5.4.x that we will fix in a future update (disclosure: I work on the tools for Apache Cordova in visual studio)

Comment: Michael, many thanks ! I've tested my solution using Cordova 5.3.3 and it seems to work. Although, I'd like to use the most recent version of Cordova CLI to gain benefits from the latest features. When do you plan to add support for Cordova 5.4.1 to the TACO ?

Comment: The next update will support 5.4.1. You should see a notification shortly to install it.