# The system cannot find the file specified (Querying ADB for attached devices)

Tags: android, cordova, adb

I am trying to deploy my cordova app into my device like so:
[image]

I already have installed ADB adn enabled USB Debugging on my phone:
[image]

[image]

Also installed PDANET on my laptop and phone

I just checked Activate USB Mode on my Phone, and I didn't click the "CONNECT INTERNET (USB)" on the PDANET in my laptop

and still I get this error:
[image]

What could be the problem? Please help..

Comment: Different things have worked for different people. This post has several solutions... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971995/getting-errors-when-deploying-cordova-app-from-visual-studio-2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971995/getting-errors-when-deploying-cordova-app-from-visual-studio-2015). None worked for me. However, I was able to install directly from the command-line. Nav to your bin where the .apk file is stored. Then, run `adb install -r .\your-app.apk`.